# how to add Message in the combobox when there is no data from web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, combobox, windows-phone

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace QuranIndeks
{
    public partial class Kategori : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        List<string> kat;

        public Kategori()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            kat = new List<string>();

            //USE DATA FROM WEB SERVIE//
            try
            {
                var ws = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
                ws.GetIndeksUmumCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetIndeksUmumCompletedEventArgs>(ws_GetIndeksUmumCompleted);
                ws.GetIndeksUmumAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Err: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        void ws_GetIndeksUmumCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetIndeksUmumCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = "";
            try
            {
                result = e.Result.ToString();
                if (result.ToString().Length > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Loaded...");
                    string[] rows1 = result.ToString().Split('|');
                    string[] lsMob;

                    for (int i = 0; i < rows1.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        lsMob = rows1[i].ToString().Split('#');
                        kat.Add(lsMob[1].ToString());
                    }
                    this.acBox.ItemsSource = kat;
                }
                else
                {




      // HERE I WANT TO SHOW MESSAGEBOX "THERE IS NO DATA" IN AUTOCOBOBOX//
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            finally
            { }        
    }
```

Comment: You're not handling the errors in any way, so drop those try/catch/finally statements to stop swallowing exceptions.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you just want to show a MessageBox or add something to a ComboBox? I also have a number of recommendations on your code, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: "*HERE I WANT TO SHOW MESSAGEBOX "THERE IS NO DATA" IN AUTOCOBOBOX*". So you want to show "THERE IS NO DATA" in combobox or messagebox? My answer assumed it is combobox where you want to show the message. *pertanyaannya agak ambigu bro :p*

Answer (score 0):

```
acBox.Items.Add("There is no data");
acBox.DataBind();
```

Not really sure with my answer, I just answered it based on my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to call `.ToString()` from object that already of type String (f.e. `result` is string, so `result.Length` is enough instead of `result.ToString().Length`).
2. Don't overuse `try/catch/finally`, moreover in early development phase. That will hide exceptions from developer him self.

You can try this :

```
void ws_GetIndeksUmumCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetIndeksUmumCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = "";
    result = e.Result.ToString();
    if (result.Length > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Loaded...");
        string[] rows1 = result.Split('|');
        string[] lsMob;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows1.Length; i++)
        {
            lsMob = rows1[i].Split('#');
            kat.Add(lsMob[1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //if no data returned from web service, 
        //add string "THERE IS NO DATA" to list
        kat.Add("THERE IS NO DATA");
    }
    this.acBox.ItemsSource = kat;
}
```